# Remote Login Connection timed out

Tags: linux, connection, kali-linux, timeout, remote-login

I have got two virtual machines kali rolling and security onion (linux distributions) and trying to exploit open ports of security onion from kali. Scan give me three open ports 22 (ssh), 443 (https) and 514 (shell). I am connecting 514 port for remote login with command:

```
rlogin -l root ipaddress
```

but it says connection timed out. However both vms can ping each other successfully so I dont think its a connection issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: These VMs are configure to allow root to connect remotely?

Comment: I have installed rsh-client in one vm to be able to use rlogin without having any password but I haven;t configure anything on destination vm yet. Should I?

Comment: In each vm can you `rlogin -l root localhost` ?

Comment: In kali vm connection is getting refused but it works fine in the other one to which actually I want to get access.